# Facebook User's Name in Text Template

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, aggregation, caption

For a given activity Aggregation's caption, is it possible to reference the Facebook user's first and/or last name? Something similar to `{profile.firstname}`, but instead of a object type of Profile, just pulling from the Facebook user's data directly?

Comment: I couldn't find it either. I suspect that because it's on the person's timeline, FB may have decided that allowing you to use their name may be redundant... who knows..